# Calling spring get rest service from angular 5

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-rest

Does Angular allow making a call to a spring rest get service with the flexibility of passing in a json payload. I did some research but did not find a way. So just want to confirm with someone more experienced in angular

Comment: Yes you can make sure you are marking the controller as `@RestController` and use `@RequestBody` for GET or POST methods to transform request parameters to java objects

Comment: No. How can you expect a get call with payload.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can achieve through @RestController and make sure you are running Spring Rest end points and angular UI was running on same port, else you need to configure CORS using @CrossOrigin anotation at controller or method level.